# Algorithm to translate list operations to be index based

Tags: algorithm, list, time-complexity

Assume you have an unsorted list of distinct items. for example:

```
['a', 'z', 'g', 'i', 'w', 'p', 't']
```

You also get a list of Insert and remove operations. Insert operations are composed of the index to insert to, and the item to insert. For example: Insert(5, 's')

Remove operations are expressed using the element to remove. For example: Remove('s')

So a list of operations may look like this:

- Insert ('s', 5)
- Remove ('p')
- Insert ('j', 0)
- Remove ('a')

I am looking for the most efficient algorithm that can translate the list of operations so that they are index based. That means that there is no need to modify the insert operations, but the remove operations should be replaced with a remove operation stating the **current** index of the item to be removed (not the original one).

So the output of the example should look like this:

- Starting set: ['a', 'z', 'g', 'i', 'w', 'p', 't']
- Insert('s', 5) ( list is now: ['a', 'z', 'g', 'i', 'w', 's', 'p', 't']
- Remove (6) (list is now: ['a', 'z', 'g', 'i', 'w', 's', 't']
- Insert('j', 0) (list is now: ['j', 'a', 'z', 'g', 'i', 'w', 's', 't']
- Remove(1) (list is now: ['j', 'z', 'g', 'i', 'w', 's', 't']

Obviously, we can scan for the next item to remove in the set after each operation, and that would mean the entire algorithm would take O(n*m) where n is the size of the list, and m is the number of operations.

The question is - is there a more efficient algorithm?

Comment: To be super clear, the inserts are performed in the order given?  So an early insert at index 0, will shift the contents of the array, making a subsequent insert at index 5 refer to a different element?  Also note, your O(n*m) assertion assumes that inserts happen in constant time, which I think isn't so.

Comment: A list structure is optimized for iteration, not for indexing. Perhaps you'd be happier with a set?

Comment: @danh you assumptions about the inserts and remove ops are correct. Regarding the insert and remove complexity - In this specific case we ignore the time spent on the actual list operations because we are not really performing them. Only collecting and translating insert and remove ops

Comment: @MarkRansom from what I understand sets have no concept of index. Doesn't seem to be what OP is looking for

Comment: No there isn't anything more efficient. To reference specific indexes like this you need arrays. You can't insert at the front of an array without shifting all other values. `O(n*m)` is the best you can get

Comment: @MitchelPaulin the question didn't get into any details on *why* addressing by index was important. The main point I was trying to get across was that a list was probably the wrong data structure.

Comment: @MarkRansom his insert and remove command is by index...

Comment: @MitchelPaulin a map then. The index is the key and the value is stored with it. You can get to O(1) with a hash map, although the constant overhead may get to be a bit much.

Comment: Please note that there is no mention of actually performing an insert or remove. The complexity of the list or set are not important because we only try to translate a list of operations, not to actually perform the operations.

Comment: There are usually tradeoffs to every data structure. Do you mean a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list?

Answer (score 0):

You can make this more efficient *if* you have access to all of the `remove` operations ahead of time, *and* they are significantly (context-defined) shorter than the object list.

You can maintain a list of items of interest: those to be removed.  Look up their initial positions -- either in the original list, or upon insertion.  Whenever an insertion is made at position `n`, each element of this list past that position gets its index increased by one; for each such deletion, decrease by one.

This is little different from methods already obvious; it's merely quantitatively faster, a potentially smaller `m` on the **O(n*m)** complexity.